# My Server is up but when I try to connect to it I am getting an error [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following a tutorial on Node.js and I think I have done everything to the letter, I run my server (node web.js) and tried to connect to it but I am getting an error. My code is given below, I saw an answer to a similar question but I avoided the error there, I just don't know whats wrong. Please help!

```
var http = require("http");

function process_request(req, res) {
    var body = 'Thanks for calling!\n';
    var content_length = body.length;
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Length': content_length,
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
}

var s = http.createServer(process_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the content that you are sending back as a response. Add this after your `res.writeHead()`.

```
 res.write(body);
 res.end();
```

Comment: res.end method you need to pass body

Comment: @Sumeet The parameters to `res.end` are optional. It just closes the response.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the error, but you could try a

```
res.send(body);
```

Instead.  Also confirm you're hitting http://localhost:**8080**/ (assuming it's running on localhost).

Comment: res.send id not method in node.js , express has

Comment: That is right @Sumeet, I forget send isn't built in.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating content but not sending to client , using res.end you can do like

```
 res.write("Hello World");
    res.end(body)
```